Можно ли использовать модель YOLOv11 без ultralytics?
Можно ли использовать для детекции модель Yolov11 через Pytorch или OpenCV. Если можно, то как? Или найти какую-либо замену, чтобы можно было легко обучить и использовать модель через Pytorсh или OpenCV?

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Можно сконвертировать модель YOLO в один из поддерживаемых OpenCV форматов (например, в ONNX):
yolo export model=yolov11.pt format=onnx

Далее использовать в OpenCV с помощью метода readNetFromONNX:
cv::dnn::Net net = cv::dnn::readNetFromONNX('yolov11.onnx');

Далее всё как с другими сетями в OpenCV, только формат выходных данных может отличаться.
